# How to filter objects using streams by their attributes?

Tags: java, arraylist, filter, java-stream

Hello there my fellow programmers,
recently is school we were asked to learn streams API, and i fell in love with them. Unfortunately I'm not skilled enough for the proper usage of them. I need to use streams to filter trough around 23 Buildings (treated as Objects) by their respective attributes. Let me demonstrate: 
Here is my Building class:

```
class Building  {
    String color;
    int position;
    int cost;
    int rent;
    int owner;

//ArrayList for storing all of the buildings
    public static ArrayList<Building> Buildings = new ArrayList<>();

//getter of the position of this building
    public int getBuildingPosition() {
        return position;
    }

//constructor:
    public Building(int position, int cost, int rent, String color, int owner) {
        Buildings.add(this);
    }
}
```

And here is an example of my Building object

```
Building buld1 = new Building(1, 50, 6, "gray", 0);
```

Now here comes the fun, because when i tried to filter it trough this stream code:

```
public static Building getBuildingByPosition(int pos) {
        List<Building> all = Building.Buildings
        .stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getBuildingPosition() == pos) // here may be the error
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return all.get(0);
    }
```

it returned an exception 
*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0*.
It seems like my *.filter()* is incorrectly written, so it doesn't pass any elements.

Can somebody show me how to filter it properly please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you add the Building to your static list but you're not initializing this object, the fields are all empty

```
public Building(int position, int cost, int rent, String color, int owner) {
    this.position = position;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.rent = rent;
    this.color = color;
    this.owner = owner;
    Buildings.add(this);
}
```

If you want to return only one object satisfying your filter use findFirst that return an Optional

```
public static Building getBuildingByPosition(int pos) {
    Optional<Building> building = Building.Buildings
    .stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getBuildingPosition() == pos)
    .findFirst();
    return building.orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: This is what was the problem, thanks a lot for that. Seems like it was a problem around ArrayLists, and not around streams at all then huh.

Comment: Oh also, the Optional isn't working, because you cannot convert from Optional<Building> to Building

Comment: @MikuldaKopecky where ?, if you mean the getBuildingByPosition method, the return statement convert optional<building> to building. The istruction building.orElse(null) mean return building if exists or null otherwise. If it's somewhere else show the code where it pose problem

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the following line `return all.get(0);`

You try to access element with index 0 but list is empty because none of the objects match filter criteria.

If there should either be 0 or 1 objects with at given position then you could use write something like this:

```
public static Optional<Building> getBuildingByPosition(int pos) {
    Optional<Building> buildingAtPos= Building.Buildings
    .stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getBuildingPosition() == pos) 
    .findFirst();
    return buildingAtPos;
}
```

Note that now we wrap Building inside `Optional`, this is commonly used in situations where there might or might not be value present.

If you always want to return `Building` or null if there isn't any building you could write it like this, but first solution is suggested way to do it:

```
public static Optional<Building> getBuildingByPosition(int pos) {
    Optional<Building> buildingAtPos= Building.Buildings
    .stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getBuildingPosition() == pos) 
    .findFirst();
    return buildingAtPos.orElse(null);
}
```

Another option you could use if you want to enforce presence of that building:

```
public static Optional<Building> getBuildingByPosition(int pos) {
    Optional<Building> buildingAtPos= Building.Buildings
    .stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getBuildingPosition() == pos) 
    .findFirst();
    return buildingAtPos.orElseThrow(()-> new IllegalStateException("Building at position " + pos + " must exist"));
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, man. i was just worried that my filter is incorrect, but as @billal GHILAS mentioned, the values weren't initialized. Your answer did wield a lot of new info that will be used int the future tho. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Your filter are correct. I thin Building class constructor. Please set member variable for filter.

```
//constructor:
public Building(int position, int cost, int rent, String color, int owner) {
    this.position = position;
    Buildings.add(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was the list was empty and you were trying to access the first element which doesn't exists.  you can use **findAny** or **findFirst** which returns **optional** to avoid accessing a potentially null object, which allows you to set a default value if the object is null

```
return Building.Buildings
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getBuildingPosition() == pos)
                .findAny().orElse(null);
```